# Paginate results of certutil -view

Tags: powershell, certificate, certificate-authority, certutil

I'm using the following command to get a list of issued certificates in a Windows Server machine with Active Directory Certificate Services (ADCS) installed.

`certutil -restrict 'Disposition=20' -out 'Binary Certificate' -view`

It's all working fine and I get a list of X509 strings. Now, I want the same results, but with some type of pagination, so I can get a specific number of issued certificates for each call of this comand.

I didn't found anything in the [man page for certuitl](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil), but I'm able to use other tools to get it done, even if some Powershell utility is needed.

Just for clarification, I'm using this command through a script that calls it over [WinRM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/remote/how-to-enable-windows-remote-shell) connection, so I need to solve it programmatically.

Currently, when I use the command I got a long string with all isued certificates. For example, if I have 3 issued certificates the output of this command will be:

```
Row 1:
  Binary Certificate:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----


Row 2:
  Binary Certificate:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----


Row 3:
  Binary Certificate:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

*For this example, I repeated the same certificate 3 times, but the a real result will bring 3 differente certificates*

What I want is something like : `certutil -restrict 'Disposition=20' -out 'Binary Certificate' -view -page 1 -pagesize 2` (**This command does not exists**) that will bring exactly same info, but just with 2 certificates and then use the same command with `-page 2` that will bring the last one.

Is it possible?

***Info:***

- Windows Server 2016 (The ideal solution should work with older versions too)
- Powershell 5.1

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to pipe `Out-Host -Paging`. This will let you advance with space bar one page at a time.

`certutil -restrict 'Disposition=20' -out 'Binary Certificate' -view | Out-Host -Paging`

You can also count the results of this command:

```
$f = certutil -restrict 'Disposition=20' -out 'Binary Certificate' -view | Select-Object Name | Measure
$f.Count
```

Comment: Thanks. Are there any way to do it programmatically? I forgot to mention in my question that I'm doing it through a script. I'll update my question with this information.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you expect to be returned?

Comment: I'll try to improve my question with the exactly behaviour that I expect, but basically I want some way to get a specific number of issued certificates each time I use the command using some type of pagination.

Comment: So you can pipe `select -first 10` or `select -last 10` to get only the first 10 items or last 10, etc. What you could also do is make that a variable, get all the results and divide by how many pages you want. IE. there are 12 results when you count all and you want 4 pages of 3 certs each, you can divide the result of count (12) by page (4) to get a result size of 3 objects per page. Then, you can run the command multiple times with `|select 1..3` then `|select 4..6` then `|select 7..9` etc to return the resultset you want.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that, since the output of certutil is a raw text, I need to know some info before parse it using select right (I need to know how many certificates I have before use it)? However, due to the lack of something native or built-in with certutil, this is the best option. if you edit your question to include it as an anwer, I'll accept it. Thanks for the help!